# ExactTarget and CSS use on templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, css

I created an e-mail template, of Paste HTML type, with the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .test1{color:#FF0000}
        .test2{color:#00FF00}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="teste1">TEMPLATE PARAGRAPH
    </p>
    <custom type="content" name="Mail content">     
    <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
</body>
```

After I created an e-mail, using the email template above, with the code below:

```
<p class="test2">CONTENT PARAGRAPH</p>
```

On all e-mails present by ExactTarget the use of css classes are respected. When the e-mail come to my gmail inbox, it comes in a plain text (without CSS formatting) and I can't figure out why!

Someone can help me with this issue or assure that only inline styles work on ExactTarget e-mails and template e-mails?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily a SFMC/ExactTarget issue.  Could be just be a Gmail thing.  I'd refer to the [Campaign Monitor The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for CSS compatibility between mail clients, to make sure.  If you do a lot of this kind of thing, you can't beat [Litmus](http://litmus.com/) for render testing.

You can also just start with a [Responsive Email Pattern](http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/), which is part of the excellent [Responsive Email Resources](http://responsiveemailresources.com/) site.

There are some instances in SFMC where rendering is different in Send Preview test sends vs actual sends (using a [Guided Send](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/guided_send/) or [User-Initiated Send](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/)).  [SFMC headers and footers](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-ZA/documentation/exacttarget/admin/account_settings/modifying_the_headers_and_footers_of_your_email_messages/) are usually the culprit.  You might check those under Admin.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know GMAIL strips the header tag, so placing the style tag within give you the expected result - no styling.